# Ability of Eclipse to work with remote SVN working copy

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-pdt

I could not find the same question on Internet although there are similar ones.

I work with a local Eclipse (Kepler) + PDT on a Windows machine. There is on a remote Linux server. The server is not a part of our office network, so we can not access it as mapped drive.

What I want to do is to checkout on the remote server a new SVN working copy from the SVN repo. Then I will create a project in Eclise. I would like this project to be connected to the SVN copy and to be able to commit, update to SVN plus all the changes that I do to be done on the remote server. Basically, no local files will be kept, the only thing that is local is the Eclipse instalation. I am not sure if I can go this with Remote System Explorer as I have not used it before and I am not sure if it will give me access to the SVN controls in Eclipse.

Thank you

EDIT: The situation is this. I have no WAMP installed on my local computer or SVN and I will never have: these are requirements. The remote server is where the SVN and the LAMP is. What I wil try is to SVN checkout from the remote server to my computes and then run Eclipse locally on the SVN copy. At the same time I want any time I save a file or make a change, that change to be SFTP-ed automatically to a folder on the remote server where I can test it in a browsers. So I will end up using some way to automatically push may changes to the remote server and when happy with them SVN commit them. Sorry for going in the wrong direction with my initial suggestion.

Basically my question ended to sound more like this. **How to upload automatically any changes that I make in my project (which is a SVN copy) to a remote server?**

Comment: You're basically asking how to misuse SVN to do...something. *Why* do you want to do all your work remotely? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me.

Answer (score 2):

Whoa there.

When you use Subversion, you are suppose to use a ***local*** working copy. That is, the copy exists on your machine and not some shared drive. You should ***never*** share a copy of a Subversion working directory.

Second of all, when you use Eclipse, you should use the Eclipse Subversion plugin client to access your repository. There are two different ones: [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) and Subclipse. Subversive is a Eclipse project while Subclipse is a project of CollabNet, the people who originally wrote Subversion.

When you install either Eclipse plugin, you can use either JvaHL or SvnKit as your Subversion connector. I tend to use SvnKit because I've had bad luck with JavaHL, but JavaHL is entirely open source while SVNKit isn't. You may have to check out the various licensing agreements and see which one you may be allowed to use at work.

So to recap.

- You should checkout from this Subversion repository ***through*** eclipse using the `http://` protocol.
- You should never use the `file:///` protocol to access a Subversion repository which it sounds like you're doing. Always run `svnserve` or Apache `httpd`. It's very easy to setup `svnserve` as a Windows service, so there's really no excuse to use `file://`.